# Ubuntu WSL2 startup error "is a directory" upon adding 'alias dsa='cd /home/rj/programming' to .bashrc

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I added the following alias to .bashrc
`alias dsa='cd /home/rj/programming/dsa'` and when I type `dsa` in the shell, bash does indeed change to that directory but when the shell starts up I get a strange error:

`-bash: /home/rj/programming/dsaAbdulBari: Is a directory`

I am running this through WSL2 for Windows 10 pro using Ubuntu 20.04.

things I have tried:

- using double quotes for the alias instead of single quotes
- using a `~` instead of `/home/rj/`
- upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to 22 (because I recall that my other computer was using this version and thought, ceteris paribus, it might help)

I am nonplussed because I have this same alias on ubuntu on my other machine and it works fine.
[image: .bashrc]
[image]

Comment: that's correct - typo on my part.  I'll change it

Comment: What is your first screenshot supposed to show, exactly? Is that the entirety or your `~/.bashrc`? The error shown is usually the result of misplaced whitespace in a variable assignment e.g. `dir= /home/rj/programming/dsaAbdulBari` in place of `dir=/home/rj/programming/dsaAbdulBari`

Comment: The first screenshot is just to show the syntax I am using for the `alias` entry in `.bashrc` Those are just the first two lines - the rest was what was created when I installed ubuntu for WSL.  From what I can tell there is no issue with incorrect whitespace.

Comment: One thing that may be worth noting is that in WSL, you get a *login shell* by default (hence `-bash` rather than plain `bash` in the error message), whereas with a desktop terminal emulator you typically get a non-login shell. In a login shell, the primary user startup file is `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if it exists). In Ubuntu, it is `~/.profile` that sources `~/.bashrc`.